# Change a textbox bound text value in the set accessor

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox

I hope someone can help me with this one, I suspect I am doing something stupid. I have bound a `TextBox` so that the `Text` is bound to `InputValue`. Basically, when the text value changes I have a method (`Inches.Parse`), which examines the value and returns a well formatted string.

If there are no errors with the parsing I want the textbox to have the well formatted string called "result". However, the `TextBox` won't show the new text? Any help would be appreciated.

```
public string InputValue 
{
    get
    {
        return _inputValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_inputValue != value)
        {                                        
            bool error;
            string result = Inches.Parse(value, 64, out error);                    

            if (error != IsValid)
            {
                IsValid = error;
            }
            if (!error)
            {
                _inputValue = result;
            }
            else
            {
                _inputValue = value;
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("InputValue");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug/issue that will apparently be fixed in dot net 4.0

Basically the problem is that if a binding sets a property it does not look for `NotifyPropertyChanged` during the setter. you can workaround this issue, by calling `NotifyPropertyChanged` on the main ui thread with a dispatcher. it is done like this

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { NotifyPropertyChanged("InputValue"); });
```

put this in your setter and you should be fine..

Comment: Thanks Aran, I will try this out tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: no worries and ill have a look tomorrow at the code at work to make sure i got it right

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the `TextBox` will not update the presented value during updating of the source property it is bound to by itself.

The workaround could be to set this binding expression

```
{Binding Path=InputValue, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}
```

note the `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` this says that you will update the source manually

then you add handler to `TextBox` `LostFocus` event (so we are sure user has finished editing)

```
textBox1.LostFocus +=
(s, e) =>
  {
    var text = textBox1.Text;
    [DataSource].InputValue = text;
  };
```

So when `TextBox` loses focus the value in the datasource will be updated and formatted and then the `TextBox` will be rebound.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: some information about updatesourcetrigger is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Appreciate it.